# Google Apps 2-leg OAuth2.0 with XOAUTH2

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'm using the Google python api client to build a SignedJwtAssertionCredentials object with a **Service Account** which can be successfully used to impersonate as a user and access some APIs such as calendar, for example:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(CLIENT_ID, PRIVATE_KEY, SCOPE)
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build('calendar', 'v3', http = http)
...
```

I'm looking for a way to use these credentials to connect using IMAP and XOAUTH2, which means I need to build an XOAUTH2 string, something like:

```
'user=<EMAIL_ADDR>\1auth=Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>\1\1'
```

With a regular OAuth2, the `ACCESS_TOKEN` part can be easily refreshed and obtained.
I've tried:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
  CLIENT_ID, PRIVATE_KEY, "https://mail.google.com/",
  prn = "required_user@email.com")
credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())
```

And using `credentials.access_token` in the XOAUTH2 string, but it doesn't work.

Is there any way of converting a SignedJwtAssertionCredentials to a XOAUTH2 string?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:
http://google-mail-oauth2-tools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python/oauth2.py

and in particular `GenerateOAuth2String` which takes an access token (like the one you already have) and a username and generates the right format for XOAUTH2.  (The trick is to remember to pass `False` for the `base64_encode` parameter if you intend to use this with `imaplib` else it gets encoded twice.)

That said, from memory the service account can't actually send/receive email as itself, but if you've used domain impersonation to impersonate a user in your domain (which you mention, but I don't see in the code samples above), it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question code to include the impersonation. I've actually solved this a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

So the code in the question actually do work. The problem was that the Marketplace App was disabled for the user I tried to impersonate as.

Here is the complete code:

```
user_email = 'a@b.com'
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    CLIENT_ID, PRIVATE_KEY, "https://mail.google.com/", prn = user_email)
credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())
xoauth2_string = 'user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1' % (
    user_email, credentials.access_token)
```